# Lucene's Batch Query Performance Tuning

Tags: lucene

I currently run Lucene's query against data read from a database table. The following code read all rows from a database table and in each iteration query the Lucene's index.

For 400,000 rows of data it runs for about 18 minutes. What can I do to improve the query to speed up the query's performance?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.ParseException;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanClause.Occur;
import org.apache.lucene.search.BooleanQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.Query;
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc;
import org.apache.lucene.search.TopDocs;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

public class SearchLucene {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String indexPath="D:/indexDir";

        Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
        Directory directory;

        try {
            directory = FSDirectory.open(new File(indexPath));

            //Index Reader
            IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
            IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new
                    IndexSearcher(indexReader);
            QueryParser parser1 = new QueryParser( "FIRSTNAME",
                    analyzer);
            QueryParser parser2 = new QueryParser( "LOCATION",
                    analyzer);

            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.
                    getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/alpha;instance","myuser","mypassword");
            Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PRSN");


            while (rs.next()) {
                BooleanQuery boolQuery = new BooleanQuery();
                Query query1 = parser1.parse(rs.getString("FIRSTNAME"));
                Query query2 = parser2.parse(rs.getString("LOCATION"));
                query2.setBoost(3);

                if(rs.getString("LOCATION") != null)
                {                               
                    boolQuery.add(query1, Occur.MUST);
                    boolQuery.add(query2, Occur.MUST);
                }
                else
                {
                    boolQuery.add(query1, Occur.MUST);
                }

                int hitsPerPage = 10;
                TopDocs docs = indexSearcher.search(boolQuery, hitsPerPage);
                ScoreDoc[] hits = docs.scoreDocs;
                int end = Math.min(docs.totalHits, hitsPerPage);

                for (int i = 0; i < end; i++) {
                    Document d = indexSearcher.doc(hits[i].doc);                    
                    if(hits[i].score>5)
                    {
                        System.out.print(d.get("FIRSTNAME"));
                        System.out.print(d.get("LOCATION"));
                        System.out.println(hits[i].score);
                    }
                }
            }
            conn.close();
            indexReader.close();

        } catch (IOException | ParseException | ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to run 400k queries like that?

Comment: I need to find record match based on content similarity.

Comment: Doing output (like with System.out) will take a significant amount of time. Try timing it without the output. Is your lucene index basically indexed with every record in your DB? What user scenario are you trying to solve with this?